# PHP - Erro quando tento logar - mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa tarde pessoal, eu estava tentado estudar um sistema de cadastro usando session em php a parte do cadastro funciona normal, o problema esta na hora de logar, mesmo com a senha correta eu recebo os 2 seguintes erros:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\wamp64\www\Login\Logar.php on line 30
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
> C:\wamp64\www\Login\Logar.php on line 30
> ```

Aqui esta o trecho relevante do código:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
                $user = $_POST['user'];
                $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'admin') or die (mysqli_error());
                $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'login') or die("databse error");
                $query = mysqli_select_db($conn, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user= '".$user."' AND pass='".$pass."'");
 linha 31 >>>   $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                if($numrows !=0)
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                    {
                        $dbusername=$row['user'];
                        $dbpassword=$row['pass'];
                    }
                if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
                {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;
                //Redirect Browser
                header("Location:welcome.php");
                    }
                }
                    else
                    {
                    echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
                    }
                   }
                    else
                    {
                echo "Required All fields!";
                }
               }
    ?>
```

Toda vez que eu tento logar mesmo as informações estando corretas eu recebo o seguinte erro

> ```
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
> boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\Login\Logar.php on line 31
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erro básico de digitação.

Esta linha não faz sentido:

```
$query = mysqli_select_db($conn, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user=...
```

A função para executar uma query é esta:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user=
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: sim sim, isso mesmo amigo, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, ja encontrei o erro, desculpem pelo tempo, eis que foi falta de atenção, eu estava selecionando a DB duas vezes ao vez de executar um query.

ERRADO:  $query = ***mysqli_select_db***($conn, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user= '".$user."' AND pass='".$pass."'");

CORRETO:
 $query = ***mysqli_query***($conn, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user= '".$user."' AND pass='".$pass."'");

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde amigo, se não me engano esta faltando mais um parâmetro de acordo com o erro na mensagem.

sugiro ver no manual do php:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Obrigado por responder amigo, mas não creio que seja esta possibilidade, pelas seguintes observações: 1-$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); < descrito no manual                                                2- O cadastro ainda 1 paramentro como argumento e não aponta erros.